# I have been trying to upload marketplace Vm solution form GCP ,and am unable to find the reason why this is happening to me

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, virtual-machine, litespeed

openlitespeed-django-1-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/sriastrovastu-map/zones/us-east4-b/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a permission issue as indicated by this section.

```
"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

You would probably want to make sure the account you are using has the right [IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview).

If you are trying to submit a solution to [Cloud Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace), I would suggest you take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm).